# Mini Fridge thermostat turns on/off doesn't cool

Tags: thermostat, refrigerator, cooling

I have a Magic Chef Mini Fridge 2 door from Home Depot (HVDR430SE) that doesn't cool. It has no evaporator or condenser fan because it is a sealed unit. The thermostat clicks on, starting the compressor and turning it off also stops the compressor but nothing cools. Is the fridge worth fixing. It's new but I can't return it.

Comment: Why can't you return it?  Is it in warranty, and what would it cost to ship to MagicChef directly?

Comment: Is broken, is not made to be fixed - recycle and replace if you "can't return it" or otherwise get it solved (which will be replaced, not fixed) by the manufacturer.

Comment: I bought this from an auction for $25. I was hoping it would easily be repaired.   Guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Throw it away and go buy another, they cost more to fix than to replace.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of buying another of something that breaks.  Maybe pick out a different minifridge.